# Indian passport holder with Canada student visa, want to visit USA as a tourist

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I am studying in Canada  (London Ontario) on a student visa. Wish to visit USA during the Christmas break. How to get a US Visa?

Answer (score 2):

Visit the web page of the US embassy or consulate that is closest to you and look up the rules for tourist visa. You can find the closest embassy or consulate here: http://www.usembassy.gov/

Apart from the general rules outlined there, pay particular attention to the requirements on which consulate/embassy you need to apply with, as you may be required to prove some sort of residency in the area served by the consulate/embassy.

Answer (score 1):

Apply for a visitor visa in the usual way. The fact that you have a status of residence in Canada will have no effect on your US visitor visa application, other than allowing you entry without a return to India.

Are you driving? London -> NYC / Philadelphia / Boston is an easy trip. Rental car companies are usually fine with it but you do need to ask for extra paperwork.